Vue js, открытие в любом пути после сборки
Собираю проект через npm run build, после этого хочу открыть его, т.е. index.html, просто открыть в браузере, однако, нужно указывать base в vite.config.js, чего я не могу сделать, т.к. у каждого пользователя путь до данных файлов может быть разном. Также я хотел бы узнать, как собирать проект без изменения структуры, названий файлов?


добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! несвязанные вопросы следует задавать отдельными вопросами. оставьте, пожалуйста, один вопрос, внеся правку (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса)

Документация говорит, что в base можно указать относительный путь ./

@andreymal, вопросик еще один: после сборки у меня указываются параметры: crossorigin, type="module", из-за которых происходят ошибки: from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: chrome, chrome-extension, chrome-untrusted, data, http, https, isolated-app. что с ними делать? просто вручную удалять?

Кажется да https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/6676

@andreymal, попробовал тот способ, который ты выписал из документации, и не получилось. посмотрел тему на гитхабе, там есть какая то либа, я ее поставил, все работает. не знаешь ли, как при сборке сохранять структуру файлов? названия файлов, папки и тд

Если вы хотите сохранять структуру файлов, значит сборка вам вообще не нужна

@andreymal, вы имеете ввиду cdn? сборка мне нужна для того, чтобы усложнить деобфускацию кода, однако сделать так, чтобы создавалась не только одна папка assets с index.n.js, но те папки, которые у меня в папке src. например, src/js/hud.vue - src/js/hud.js.

Сохраняя оригинальную структуру, вы существенно упрощаете деобфускацию. У вас какие-то взаимоисключающие хотелки
